# How to find and replace symbols in a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, string

I know it must be a very simple thing to do but I've never had to treat strings before (in Objective-C) and apparently there's not RegEx on Cocoa-Touch.

Well, the situation is:

- I have a text field to get a value (money, such as 32.10 for instance).

The problem:

- If the user types in a symbol such as @, /, # etc. my app will crash.

The Question: How can I treat this string to remove the symbols if there are any?

Comment: What version of iOS are you targeting? You get increasingly better options at 3.2 and 4.

Comment: I'm working with 4. But already managed to do it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this:

```
NSString *s = @"12.827#@584";
NSCharacterSet *removeCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:@#"];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: removeCharSet] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do get regex in Cocoa Touch.

Here's a good discussion of the varying degrees of regex power in iOS, the blocks example at the end should get you most of the way there.

http://volonbolon.net/post/861427732/text-handling-in-ios-4

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're trying to figure out the number included in the UITextFields's `text` property and assign it to a float variable.

Try using an NSScanner for this:

```
NSScanner* textScanner = [NSScanner localizedScannerWithString:textfield.text];
float* floatValue;
[textScanner scanFloat:&floatValue];
```

floatValue now contains the parsed float value of your textfield.

Comment: Well, yeah, but what if I type something like 32@3$1"? I want to identify those symbols and remove them from my string or at least send an alert to the user saying that he can't type symbols.

Comment: In that string, floatValue would be 32.00. NSScanner is the most reliable method to get number values from NSStrings. In order to check if the text field contains non-numeric characters, use [NSNumberFormatter numberFromString:]. It will return nil if the string contains more than just numbers.

Comment: Just tested, it is great indeed but it won't consider commas or dots, which makes the whole float thing pointless (literally). :/
Eg: 22.10 will be read as 22.00